# Vim: Utf-8 ې character breaks displayed string

Tags: vim, utf-8

I have file that has hex content: db90 3031 46, which should be displayed in vim as "ې" followed by "01F", but what I noticed is that it is never displayed correctly. Then I noticed It is the same in other places like in terminal and browser I always get ې01F? Why is that? Just paste that in google and try yourself you will never be able to put "ې" and 0 as next character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an Arabic character with *right-to-left* indicator, so you probably need to switch back to left-to-right mode, such as with `U+200e`.

The Unicode bidirectional stuff is rather complex - the behaviour you are seeing is probably caused by the fact that the Latin digits are marked `EN = European number` (a weak type), while letters such as `F` are marked `L = left to right` (a strong type).

Weak types are treated differently in the Unicode specification, such as with this quote which covers your particular case (my emphasis):

> Problematic cases may occur when a right-to-left paragraph begins with left-to-right characters, or there are nested segments of different-direction text, or there are weak characters on directional boundaries. ***In these cases, embeddings or directional marks may be required to get the right display.***

So your code point followed by a digit renders as "ې7" (I typed that `7` in *after* the Arabic character despite the fact it's showing up before it), while following it with a *letter* gives "ېX".

For what it's worth, the text "ې‎7" was generated here by inserting `&lrm;` between the two characters, the HTML equivalent of the `U+200e` Unicode code point.

If you head on over to [this UTF-8 codec site](https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php) and enter `%u06D0%u200e7` into the decoding section, you'll see that it comes out in your desired order (removing the `%200e` shows it in the order you're describing in your question).