# nCurses: Displying Utf-8 characters with LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK

Tags: c, utf-8, ncurses

This question is a followup of the more generic one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294678/vim-utf-8-%DB%90-character-breaks-displayed-string/62294827#62294827). Using ncurses [mvwaddwstr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mvwaddwstr) I would like to always display UTF-8 characters with [LEFT-TO-RIGHT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark#:~:text=Unicode,it%20is%20E2%2080%208E%20.) mark so I can avoid improper order when mixing arabic letters `ې` and weak type letters like EN = European number like `0`. As answer for the linked question suggest it is easy when dealing with HTML(just put U+200e code point between the two) but when printing with NCurses I have to specify window specific coordinates to be printed in and that makes me scratch my head as putting that between every printed character create gaps in printed text.